# MySQL set column value from another table (JOIN 3 tables)

Tags: mysql, join

I know that there are couple similar questions like "join 3 tables" but none of that i've read helped me.

I have 3 tables:

checklists
`"id"  "description"`

project_checklists
`"id"  "checklist_id"`

project_checklists_instances
`"id"  "description"  "project_checklist_id"`

I want to fill "description" column of *project_checklists_instances* with values from "description" column of *checklists* table. 
Those 2 tables not related to each other but both have relation with *project_checklists* table.

So i've tried this query

```
UPDATE project_checklists_instances
SET description = (SELECT c.description FROM checklists c
JOIN project_checklists pc ON c.id = pc.checklist_id
JOIN project_checklists_instances pci ON pc.id = pci.project_checklist_id)
WHERE pc.id = project_checklist_id")
```

And i got error:

```
SQLiteException: no such column: pc.id (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE project_checklists_instances  SET description = (SELECT c.description FROM checklists c  JOIN project_checklists pc ON c.id = pc.checklist_id  JOIN project_checklists_instances pci ON pc.id = pci.project_checklist_id)  WHERE pc.id = project_checklist_id
```

Please point me out how i can reach desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was extra bracket, so the last line with "pc.id" was outside the scope where pc is defined.